# Почему скрипт переопределяет стиль селекта?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

Есть у меня [тестовый интернет-магазин](http://a-lot-of-money.ru/templates/22/) на *wordpress+woocommerce*. При помощи библиотеки [jQuery Form Styler](http://dimox.name/jquery-form-styler/) подключил `$('select').styler();` и стилизовал выпадающий список (добавил на страницу оформления оплаты для наглядности).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему выпадающий список в самом низу на этой же странице единственный, который не стилизуется на всем сайте?

Вернее, он с самого начала стилизуется, но через мгновение подгружается какой-то скрипт с белой пеленой и его переопределяет на изначальные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем, лучшего решения, чем переопределения с таймаутом я не нашел

```
setTimeout(function(){
$('select').styler();
console.log("yes");
},1900);
```

Answer (score 2):

Все дело в количестве скриптов которые вы грузите, styler просто прекращает работу, не добравшись до второго селекта. Локально скрипт добирается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Детали [**теста**](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/151002_02_VEK/1/details/) говорят сами за себя, рекомендую скинуть время загрузки страницы хотя бы до 3х секунд т.к. смысла от 70 скриптов с эффектами, если их никто не дождется?..

**215** реквестов **КАРЛ!!!**

Comment: на то он и тестовый) спасибо за анализ- я уловил мысль, но фишка в том, что если я на странице оставляю только нижний блок с оплатой - успеваю заметить, что стайлер добрался до 2го селекта, после появляется белая полупрозрачная пелена как при загрузке и он переопределяется заново на изначальный, поэтому считаю, что простое уменьшение времени загрузки это дело не поправит..

Comment: @Вася, о времени загрузки я говорил в том плане, что врятли кто-то примет у вас магазин, который грузит страницу больше 3х секунд т.к. потенциальный покупатель -просто уйдет с сайта или дождется, но первое впечатление о магазине сложится плохое.

по селекту - думаю styler.js конфликтует с каким-то из скриптов, которые идут дальше в очереди загрузки, а локально получилось потому, что многие скрипты просто не загрузились.

Сам я отказался от этого скрипта, в пользу html5/css3+пара скриптов чтобы в старых браузерах был порядок, которые и так нужны.

Comment: а можете где-нить привести или воспроизвести альтернативу?

Comment: @Вася, посмотреть пример можно тут -http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953 или в сети поискать `css3 style form checkbox radio select` как-то так

Comment: так там же про селекты ничего нет и запросу ничего путного не находится..

Comment: @Вася, вот лови - http://cssdeck.com/labs/styling-select-box-with-css3 , http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/XxkSC/light/

Comment: спасибо, но вы же сами видите, что результат мягко сказать не очень: плохо получается фокус, а пункты меню как были топорными, так и остались..

Comment: @Вася, это просто примеры с принципом работы от `label` который и стилизуется, ничего не мешает использовать псевдоклассы и добиться желаемого результата.
с option есть проблемы бордера, но ничего не мешает отрицательным внешним отступом их убрать, как тут слева - http://i.imgur.com/9baeoHS.png

Comment: с `label` все ясно. `option` не поддаются стилизации, вот в чем затык - мне им например банально нужно отступы сверху и снизу добавить, т.е выше сделать - я уже молчу про плавность переходов `transition`, `opacity` и `box-shadow`